# How do I get comments in MS Word 2013 to show up next to the point of insertion?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I have a document in MS Word 2013 for Windows that I have set to Track Changes. I am trying to add comments to it, as I would in a previous version of Word. However, the comments are appearing in a "stream", most recent at the top, on the upper right hand side of the page, instead of appearing next to the insertion point of where I added the comment.

I am using the "All Markup" view since the "Simple Markup" view made it so that the full text of my comments didn't render - part of it was obscured by a blank rectangle.

The fact that all my comments appear in a stream on the right hand side makes it very difficult to determine which comments are referencing what part of the document. How would I get comments to show up like they did in previous versions of Word, or is that just not possible?

Comment: Something seems broken, my comments show up on the same line they were applied, in both simple and Full markup views. Is it doing this to you in every document, or just one specific one?  Did you create the document(s) in question? What version of Word were they created in?  Have you tried "repairing" office?  Are they showing up in a pane labelled "Revisions"?  Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was going wrong here. It was because I was doing comments on a table of contents. Apparently that doesn't work the same as normal comments. Not great, but I can live with it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Word to me :)

Comment: @Adam: It probably has to be that way - otherwise regenerating the TOC would delete all the comments. Similarly with comments on text that is generated using other field types, I think.

Comment: @bibadia, Good point